# Iterate over all search results in Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor

Is there any way to iterate over all search results in Atom Editor? For example I search for something, find 50 occurrences that I want to adapt. At the moment, I click on first search result to open the file, edit the code, save and close it and then click on the next until the search result list is empty.

What would be awesome is a way to just jump to the next search result. Is there something like this, maybe via some extension?

Comment: Have you looked at this package? https://atom.io/packages/project-find-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [these comments](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/460), I installed the package [project-find-navigation](https://atom.io/packages/project-find-navigation), and added the following to my keymap.cson:

```
'atom-workspace:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-shift-M': 'project-find-navigation:activate-results-pane'
  'ctrl-shift-N': 'project-find-navigation:next'
  'ctrl-shift-P': 'project-find-navigation:prev'
```

Now I can jump to the next result by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + N, when I have the "Project Find Results" tab open in the right pane of the editor.

(If you only have one pane, right-click on it and select "Split Right", then drag the top of the tab into the right pane. I don't know why it won't work otherwise, maybe because I'm on Windows 8.1 here.)